# how to get this ajax slideshow to work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, slideshow

I'm trying to make a simple ajax slideshow. The folder contains several pics, but only the first pic is shown. Then there is no sign of ajax refresh.

Many thanks in advance, gilad

```
    <div id="gallery-container">
        <img id="gallery" src="" alt="Gallery">
    </div>



    <script>

        function imgHandler(image) {
            $('#gallery').attr('src', 'images/' + image);
            $('#gallery').load(function() {
                $('#gallery').fadeIn();
            });
        };
        function getImage(imgIndex) {
            $('#gallery').hide();
            var ajaxParams = new Array();
            ajaxParams['url'] = 'images/img.php?i=' + imgIndex;
            ajaxParams['dataType'] = 'text';
            ajaxParams['success'] = imgHandler;
            $.ajax(ajaxParams);
        }

        function index_increase() {
            index+1;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            var index = 0;
            getImage(index);

            setInterval(function() {
                getImage(index_increase);
                },500);




        });

    </script>
```

Comment: why can't you use ready to use jquery libraries for this

Comment: I asuume i can but don't know how. which functions do u recommend?

Comment: Well if your client does not have any problem you can get loads of jquery slide show plugins from google. choose one that suits your requirement best